# Why CLI response time is very slow via Command prompt?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

I am using Salesforce CLI and Visual studio code for Salesforce DX. The command prompt is taking very long time to execute the sfdx command.

Is this because the system configuration which I am using or some
 other parameters plays role here?

My system Configuration is:-

- Ram memory 4GB
- 32 bit operating system
- Window 7

Comment: Check how many RAM memory is on use in task manager. I tried to work with the following setup: Chrome, VScode, SF DX, git and all 6 GB RAM was in use and that was a reason of slow. After switching to PC with 16 GB RAM everything is perfect!

Comment: are you using proxy and it also depends what you are trying to do

Comment: The memory usage is generally 50%. After restarting the system, I found a little bit fast.

Comment: Which sfdx command? Just `sfdx` by itself or a specific command like `sfdx force:org:list`? The org list command can take a while because for each authenticated org there is at least one web request to check its status. The performance is something the CLI team is working on. You can also open issues with the team at https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli-packages

Comment: @DougAyers Thanks for your suggestion. I have raised it.

Comment: Agree with Sanket. DX is very slow, running any command. It takes about a minute to retrieve/deploy single file. There is no issue with internet or RAM. Also, it takes about 30 seconds to open default org. I am using v45.2.

Answer (score 0):

Run the cmd as administrator, that solved it for me
(I know it's late but it might help others)